# Vector field under a diffeomorphism

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds

Let $F:N \rightarrow M$ be a $C^{\infty}$ diffeomorphism of manifolds. Prove that if g is a $C^{\infty}$ function and X a $C^{\infty}$ vector field on N, then $F_\ast(gX)=(g\circ F^{-1})F_\ast X$.

I know $F_\ast X$ is a vector field since F is a diffeomorphism. But I can't see how to compute to get the result with the $F^{-1}$, any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$(F_*X)_x=dF_{F^{-1}(x)}X(F^{-1}(x))$, so we have:

$(F_*(gX)_x=dF_{F^{-1}(x)}(g(F^{-1}(x))X(F^{-1}(x))$,

$((g\circ F^{-1})F_*X)(x)=g(F^{-1}(x))F_*X(x)=g(F^{-1}(x))dF_{F^{-1}(x)}X(F^{-1}(x))$.

So the both expression are equals since $dF_{F^{-1}(x)}$ is linear.